# Does booting from a USB in Windows 7 replace the current operating system?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, usb, bootable-media

If I am using Windows 7 currently, and I boot up from a USB (with windows 10 on it), that replace Windows 7 on the computer, or will it boot up from Windows 7 again afterwards if I remove the USB?

I'm also curious about knowing how the USB will react to running the operating system, and how the computer will react to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what that USB is designed to do.  If it's considered a "Live USB" (aka Live CD), then it shouldn't touch the original OS unless it's told to.  Take out the USB, reboot, and everything should be as it originally was.

If you tell it to install Win10, then you do run the risk of it overwriting your Win7 install.

As far as a "reaction", if it's an actual Live USB, then for most purposes what you see is what it is - a full OS, it's just running off the USB.  The main thing you'll probably notice is since all of the OS files are on the USB, it'll run a little slower than if the files were on a hard drive.

Comment: But all of the files and anything I do while running the USB will stay on the USB? Also, how do I know if I have a live USB?

Comment: What did you do to create the bootable USB?

Comment: If I remember correctly, I think I either used Rufus, or I installed windows 10 and used the "Create Bootable USB" option

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't a live Win10 out there.  What you probably have is an install disk ISO put on a USB (so the computer treats it a if you have a Win10 CD).  If you run it through, it may nuke your Win7 install.